# fckEditor, CKEditor 100's of errors C#.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I recently upgraded an old C# application to 4.6 framework so that I could consume a vital service that was moving to 4.6. After I did that my fckEditor had 102 compile errors. This did not make any sense because it had been working just fine for years. So, I upgraded to CfEditor and I still have 102 errors.

An example of one of the errors is:

> 'addedCount' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

I have that type of error around 20 times.

All the errors are in the CFEditor code. Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: You aren't showing the code; all we can guess is that you have a undeclared variable

Comment: I looked up fckEditor and CfEditor and it appears that these are external editors? Is Visual Studio actually throwing errors?

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the target framework version for the package? Try doing that and cleaning and rebuilding your solution. If you're using Visual Studio, this has caused me problems in the past after applying a dramatic change like updating framework version. Try restarting the editor as well.

I am assuming that this place you're having an issue with is resolved via a package manager. Please give more context if this isn't the case.

Comment: I had copied the wrong stuff into my cfeditor folder. I removed the folder and the dll then carefully added everything back in the correct way and it worked. I do not know how all the extra files and folders got there. This is an old Web solution, I had to get it to compile in framework 4.6 so that I could consume a critical web service. It jumped from 3.0 to 4.6.

Comment: This was deleted by me.

Comment: Glad to hear it, everything working as expected now?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying. Last night, right before I stopped for the day. I removed the folder and the DLL and then added everything back in and Walla! Everything worked. It looked like the folder that I removed had stuff in it that didn't belong.